ValueError when loading sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier pickle in Python 3.10
I'm encountering an issue while transitioning from Python 3.7.3 to Python 3.10 due to the deprecation of the older version. The problem arises when attempting to load a pickled sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier model. Environment:
Original: Python 3.7.3, scikit-learn 0.23.1 Current: Python 3.10, scikit-learn 1.3.2
Problem: When loading the pickled model, I receive the following error:
ValueError: node array from the pickle has an incompatible dtype:
- expected: {'names': ['left_child', 'right_child', 'feature', 'threshold', 'impurity', 'n_node_samples', 'weighted_n_node_samples', 'missing_go_to_left'], 'formats': ['<i8', '<i8', '<i8', '<f8', '<f8', '<i8', '<f8', 'u1'], 'offsets': [0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56], 'itemsize': 64}
- got : [('left_child', '<i8'), ('right_child', '<i8'), ('feature', '<i8'), ('threshold', '<f8'), ('impurity', '<f8'), ('n_node_samples', '<i8'), ('weighted_n_node_samples', '<f8')]

Code:
import pickle

for m in models:
    file = 'finalized_model_' + m + '.sav'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(file, 'rb'))
    df[m] = loaded_model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]

Attempted Solution: I've tried to mitigate this issue by loading and re-saving the model using a higher protocol:
import pickle
from sklearn import model_selection

# Load the model
with open("path_to_old_model.pkl", 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file)

# Re-save using a higher protocol
with open("path_to_updated_model.pkl", 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    print(m)

However, after upgrading the environment to Python 3.10 and the latest version of scikit-learn, I still encounter the same error when attempting to load the re-saved model. Is there a way to successfully load these models in the newer Python environment without losing their functionality? Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

This is why you shouldn't use pickle to save objects. But this is not pickle fault. Basically the problem is that the underlying scikit-learn object has evolved. As is you probably will not be able to salvage this. Best way to proceed would be to upgrade the learning pipeline too.
